# Has there been loss of natural habitat in north England?

Tags: homework, gis

Has there been loss of natural habitat in north England or Britain in general over the past years? If there was, what is the loss in percentage? A reference would be highly appreciated

Comment: This seems rather specific, such that it would not be very useful to the general public user and that few would know of such.  Suggest you do a detailed search of Google Scholar and perhaps more applicable journal sites, try to write/call experts in your area, and try your own research.  Based on https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Population_density_UK_2011_census.png/250px-Population_density_UK_2011_census.png, if you're thinking of only areas north of the M62 as north England, it may not be that much, though agriculture may be taking some too.  What's it for?

Comment: `over the past years` How many years do you mean? `north England or Britain` You should be specific about what geographical/political areas you mean by these terms, perhaps a map would help.

Comment: Ha! one says too specific the other says too broad. Thanks for the response both. @nmtoken whole of Britain is fine, regarding years I'm unsure how it works but I guess past 50 years would work. Jeopardy thanks for the direction this is for homework in GIS

Comment: First define what you mean by 'loss of habitat' - urbanization?, deforestation?, transition from deciduous to coniferous?, degree of fragmentation?, loss of wetland? Loss of habitat for one species can be gain of habitat for another.

Comment: thanks @GordonStanger clearly I'm a bit out of my depth here. I guess looking at a simplest way possible would be forestry area in general (either deciduous or coniferous)? Not sure about wetland, is it of significance in that area?